# I need to read the epub file in ionic application

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

I tried to read the `epub file` using `epub.min.js` but I didn't get an output.
In body tag I wrote the code:

```
<div onclick="Book.prevPage()">‹</div>
<div id="area"></div>
<div onclick="Book.nextPage()">›</div>
<script src="js/zip.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/epub.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var Book = ePub('../epub/ANewDay');
    Book.renderTo('area');//div id
    EPUBJS.Render.Iframe.prototype.setLeft = function(leftPos){
    this.document.documentElement.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate("-" + leftPos +"px", 0)';
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any console errors? Try playing around with this file path:

```
var Book = ePub('../epub/ANewDay');
```

if your epub/ directory is a direct child of www/ try "epub/ANewDay" for your file path. Also check file extension.

Comment: i didn't got any error in chrome developer tool.
Is there any plugin available for read an epub file.

Comment: I got an below error sometine.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource